# Validating nested dict with Pydantic `create_model`

Tags: python, validation, fastapi, typechecking, pydantic

I am using create_model to validate a config file which runs into many nested dicts. In the below example i can validate everything except the last nest of sunrise and sunset.

```py
class System(BaseModel):

    data: Optional[create_model('Data', type=(str, ...), daytime=(dict, ...))] = None

try:
    p = System.parse_obj({
        'data': {
            'type': 'solar',
            'daytime': {
                'sunrise': 5,
                'sunset': 10
            }
        }})

    print(p.dict())
    vals = p.dict()
    print(vals['data']['daytime'], type(vals['data']['daytime']['sunrise']))

except ValidationError as e:
    print(e)
```

How can i incorporate a nested dict in create_model and ensure sunrise and sunset are validate or is there any other way to validate this. ?

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve, so here's my best guess:

Pydantic's [`create_model()`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation) is meant to be used when

> the shape of a model is not known until runtime.

From your code it's not clear whether or not this is really necessary.

Here's how I would approach this.

(The code below is using Python 3.9 and above type hints. If you're using an earlier version, you might have to replace `list` with `typing.List` and `dict` with `typing.Dict`.)

### Using a "Static" Model

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, create_model
from typing import Optional

class Data(BaseModel):
    type: str
    daytime: dict[str, int] # <- explicit types in the dict, values will be coerced

class System(BaseModel):
    data: Optional[Data]

system = {
    "data": {
        "type": "solar",
        "daytime": {
            "sunrise": 1,
            "sunset": 10
        }
    }
}

p = System.parse_obj(system)
print(repr(p))
# System(data=Data(type='solar', daytime={'sunrise': 1, 'sunset': 10}))
```

This will accept integers in `daytime` but not other types, like strings.

That means, something like this:

```py
system = {
    "data": {
        "type": "solar",
        "daytime": {
            "sunrise": "some string",
            "sunset": 10
        }
    }
}

p = System.parse_obj(system)
```

will fail with:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for System
data -> daytime -> sunrise
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
```

If you want more control over how `"daytime"` is being parsed, you could create an additional model for it, e.g.:

```py
class Daytime(BaseModel):
    sunrise: int
    sunset: int

class Data(BaseModel):
    type: str
    daytime: Daytime

class System(BaseModel):
    data: Optional[Data]
```

This will work as above however, only the parameters `sunrise` and `sunset` will be parsed and everything else that might be inside `"daytime"` will be ignored (by default).

### Using a "Dynamic" Model

If you really need to create the model dynamically, you can use a similar approach:

```py
class System(BaseModel):
    data: Optional[
        create_model(
            "Data",
            type=(str, ...),
            daytime=(dict[str, int], ...), # <- explicit types in dict
        )
    ] = None

system = {
    "data": {
        "type": "solar",
        "daytime": {
            "sunrise": 1,
            "sunset": 10
        }
    }
}

p = System.parse_obj(system)
print(repr(p))
```

will work, while

```py
system = {
    "data": {
        "type": "solar",
        "daytime": {
            "sunrise": "abc",
            "sunset": 10
        }
    }
}

p = System.parse_obj(system)
```

will fail with

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for System
data -> daytime -> sunrise
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
```